# Open a link in webBrowser control in external browser?

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I want the links in my Webbrowser control to open in the default browser and not in the Windows control.

The exact same problem was tackled in the below link and I followed the same solution of intercepting the navigating event and canceling it.

[How to open a link in webBrowser control in external browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035579/how-to-open-a-link-in-webbrowser-control-in-external-browser)

But when I implement the solution, it works well when Chrome is the default browser. When IE (Ver 10) is the default browser, clicking the link opens the URL in the same webbrowser control.
Any ideas?

Comment: can you write some browser compatibility code of your own to check which Browser it's being launched or invoked from...?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't get the suggestion.. But the link is being launched from the Webbrowser control and if Chrome is the default browser, it loads in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process.Start "Starts (or reuses) the process resource that is specified by the StartInfo property of this Process component and associates it with the component."

I suspect that since the WebBrowser control is actually a stripped down IE browser, using Process.Start reuses the WebBrowser control rather than launching a new instance of iexplore.exe.

You might need to have your code check the registry to see what the user's default browser is ([Windows Registry key for "check whether IE is the default browser"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222367/windows-registry-key-for-check-whether-ie-is-the-default-browser)).  If you find that the default browser is set to IE, then change the Process.Start method to explicitly launch iexplore.exe

```
Process.Start("iexplore.exe",e.Url.ToString());
```

Comment: Yes. The issue was that there was no default browser selected. I would also want to add that if Chrome is installed, even if no default browser is selected, Chrome would be used and the link opens in chrome. If chrome is not installed, we need to explicitly make IE the default browser to make the links open in IE.