# How to always open a link in new IE window when clicking images, etc in web browser control

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm a beginner in **VB.NET**. I make a **winform application** now. There is a web browser control in the form, which has a very small size. So when the wb control loads a website, users see only a partial image area of the website, but this is not wrong. I want to always open links in a new IE window, but it's  absolutely impossible. Whenever I click a image which had a link, the linked web page is displayed in a small sized wb control in the form instead of an external IE new window. I want to always open links in external IE new windows when users click a image in wb control of winform. Is this possible? I use **Visual Studio 2015 Community Version** in **Windows 10**.The solution may be in **C#** as well.
Thanks ahead.

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035579/how-to-open-a-link-in-webbrowser-control-in-external-browser). It's in C#, but it can be converted into VB.Net.

Comment: Do you actually mean IE as in Internet Explorer or just the standard browser? Unless you have absolute control over the websites opened by your application and their compatibility, forcing your users to use an outdated browser might not be the best idea.

Comment: first to han, i paste the linked reply regard navigating event. but that's not in my case maybe. thanks to your interest. next to asherah, must open external web browser window. not only IE but also chrome, firefox, etc..

Comment: i paste best answer linked by han and asherah in my application, then in debugging i click a image then linked web page is displayed in same wb control. what prblem do i have?

Comment: Do you know how to use breakpoints in Visual Studio? Put a breakpoint in the line Process.Start() and run the project. See if it stops in that line when you click a link in the WebBrowserControl.

Comment: i tried other QnA solutions. on their way i click a image with leftbtn and ctrl key then linked webpage opened in new in window. but today open link in wb control.

Comment: maybe my window 10 conditions is something wrong.

Comment: Why don't you post your code? Edit your question and put the code. But please make it simple.

Comment: i apply breakpoint that line. in debugging full sized ie browser displayed. and in script window in vs2015 'process.start(e.url.tostring())' are yellow backcolored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private firstTime As Boolean = True

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.bing.com")

        While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        WebBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(50, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating

        If firstTime Then
            firstTime = False
        Else
            Process.Start("IExplore.exe", e.Url.ToString())
            e.Cancel = True
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Han Thank u so much. your script only read no debug now. I tried process.start and e.cancel = true script. but still opened in wb control instead of external default browser. my application have no radiobutton control. my goal is that user see a image and click it. then automatically popup in new dafault browser on user's os. so here the event is clicking the image not choosing the button. simply clicking only. I don't know what event needed.

Comment: unforturnately, the way to choose radiobutton seems to be not proper.(?) i'm sorry i am beginner in english too. simply clicking only then popup external window of default browser. i think that simply click then popup external window is very basic skills. but never simple in programming. it's my mistake. the reason why is that user click right mouse button on image then display shortcut menu. then user select 'open link in new window' then linked web page displayed in new window of IE. I thought this basic process can run by vb programming. but impossible in my skill.

Comment: in example above, user click on "google" image, then linked web page is displayed in new window. this is my goal only. seen simple but never simple in programming. i am beginner in programming.

Comment: @bbond I add radiobuttons so you can choose which browser to use as external browser. If you just want to use IE just use `Process.Start("IExplore.exe", e.Url.ToString())`.

Comment: @bbond Just to make sure, did you put your code in the `Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating`?

Comment: yes. i tried many solutions for 2days. but still open in same wb control. only open in new window when in manual - real behavior not in scripted program.

Comment: just you great really. you so cool. your solution worked very well. whatever dafault browser is, links are opened in new window defaulted browser. still i can't understand your solution fully, i think "dim firsttime as boolean = true" is vey important function. i don't understand this. thank u for your devotion.

Comment: han! thank you for your devotion and interest. i got a valuable step. really.

Comment: i revised script a little bit. deleted while ~ end while script. added webbrowser1_documentcompleted ~ procedure. and pasted WebBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(50, 0) in documentcompleted ~ procedure. and in navigating procedure, Process.Start("IExplore.exe", e.Url.ToString()) -> Process.Start(e.Url.ToString()). and www.bing.com is displayed vertical and horizental scrollbars. this is not intended. and a certain site navigated is displayed automatically many advertising html documents just not clicked. but this problem is not main topic

Comment: The purpose of firstTime variable is to allow the WebBrowserControl to navigate its destination for the first time only. If you remove it, the WebBrowserControl stays blank and an external browser pops up.